# Scroll to the first div of the dynamically added data

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I'm making an endless scroller.

When I press the 'Get more posts' button, after the data has been added, it should scroll down to the first post (which is in a div) of the dynamically added data.

So I want to get the FIRST DIV of the dynamically added data.

I'm trying to make jQuery find the div id (which is a post_id number of a post) after the last post that got added, and then make jQuery find the next lowest post number (which should be the FIRST div id of the dynamically added data). And then it should scroll down to that.

For example:

```
    <div id = "5">
        //Post.
    </div>
    <div id = "4">
        //Post.
    </div>

    //THIS IS THE DYNAMICALLY ADDED CONTENT, IT IS ONLY ADDED AFTER THE AJAX CALL WITH JQUERY.
    <div id = "2"> //<--- It should scroll down to that one.
        //Post.
    </div>
    <div id = "1">
        //Post.
    </div>
//Dynamically added content ends.

<script type = "text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#get-more-post').click(function(){

    var post_id = $('div.Posted:last').attr('rel');
    //In this case, the post_id = 4.

    $.post("add_more_post.php", {post_id: post_id} , function(data){
        if(data){
            var scroll_div = //I want jQuery to find the post which is lower than post_id = 4, that is post_id = 2. How is it done?;
            parent.$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $("div#"+scroll_div).offset().top; }, "slow");
        }
    });
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work.

```
var scrollDiv = $("#4").next("div").attr("id");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/637eT/1/